# Show the following series convergent to $EX_1$ almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

> Suppose random variables $X_{1},\ X_{2},\cdots$ are integrable independent indentical distributed
>
> I want to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{X_{k}}{k} \sim  EX_{1} \log n $ a.s.

Comment: Try using summation by parts and the SLLN.

Comment: Also see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310092/an-application-of-the-law-of-large-numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An application of the law of large numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310092/an-application-of-the-law-of-large-numbers)

Comment: @ClementC.I checked it. But the status is 'put on hold'. I think I put additional assumption which is 'in $L^1$'. And I saw your comment which tag another problem. It has a little mistake on it. So I think this question should not be on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the same way as the proof of Kolomogorov's SLLN. Firstly,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty&\mathsf{P}(|X_k|> k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathsf{P}(|X_1|> k)\le \mathsf{E}|X_1|<\infty\\
\text{by Borel-Cantelli Lemma}\quad&\implies \mathsf{P}(\{|X_k|>k\}\; \text{i.o.})=0.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Secondly, 
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{E}[X_k1_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]=\mathsf{E}[X_11_{\{|X_1|\le k\}}]\to \mathsf{E}[X_1]\qquad \text{as $k\to\infty$}\\
&\qquad \implies\frac1{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mathsf{E}[X_k1_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]}{k}\to \mathsf{E}[X_1]\qquad \text{as $n\to\infty$} \tag{2}
\end{align}
At last,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty&\frac{\mathsf{Var}[X_k1_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]}{k^2\log^2 k}
\le \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\mathsf{E}[X_k^21_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]}{k^2}<\infty\\
&\implies \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{X_k1_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}-\mathsf{E}[X_k1_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]}{k\log k}\qquad\text{convergence a.s.}\\
\text{by Kronecker Lemma}&\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{X_k1_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}-\mathsf{E}[X_k1_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]}{k}= 0 \;\text{a.s.}\\
\text{by (2)}\quad&\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{X_k1_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}}{k}=\mathsf{E}[X_1]\qquad\text{a.s.}\tag{3}\\
\text{by (1)}\quad&\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{X_k}{k}=\mathsf{E}[X_1]\qquad\text{a.s.}\tag{4}
\end{align}
Complement: (3): Using following fact: If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, then
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\log n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{a_k}{k}=a$, (3) could be proved directly or be deduced from Stolz-Cesàro theorem.  
(4): 
\begin{align}
\{\omega:(|X_k(\omega)|>k)\;\text{i.o.}\}^c&=\{\omega:(X_k(\omega)\ne X_k(\omega)1_{\{|X_k(\omega)|\le k\}}) \;\text{except a finite number of $k$}\}\\
&\subset\Bigl\{\omega: \lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl[\frac1{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{X_k(\omega)}{k}-\frac1{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{X_k(\omega)1_{\{|X_k(\omega)|\le k\}}}{k}\Bigr]=0\Bigr\}.
\end{align}
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mathsf{E}[X_k^21_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]}{k^2}<\infty$:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mathsf{E}[X_k^21_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]}{k^2}
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mathsf{E}[X_1^21_{\{|X_1|\le k\}}]}{k^2}
\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac4{t^2}\mathsf{E}[|X_1|^21_{|X_1|\le t}] \,dt\\
&\quad=4\int_0^\infty\frac1{t^2}\mathsf{E}[|X_1|^21_{|X_1|\le t}]\,dt 
\qquad\text{(Exchange the order of integration)}\\ &\quad=4\int_0^\infty y^2\Bigl(\int_y^\infty\frac1{t^2}\,dt\Bigr)dF_{|X_1|}(y) =4\int_0^\infty ydF_{|X_1|}(y)=4\mathsf{E}[|X_1|]<\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: @kayak, thank you for your replication. I add some interpretation.

Comment: Oh thanks! At last, why is $\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\mathsf{E}[X_k^21_{\{|X_k|\le k\}}]}{k^2}<\infty$?

Comment: @kayak, thank you for your replication. I add an interpretation at the end.